# Flink Operator View UID

Tags: apache-flink

How can I view Flink Operator custom UID that I have set?

Regardless of what I have set up, the log seems to print internal ID:

```
"[runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph] - Source: Custom Source (1/1) (**778566c5e29980d5f3c269f08260fd5a**) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING."
```

UID is not shown the the dashboard as well.

So, I can't really tell if the UID I set has been used or not.

Answer (score 0):

UIDs can be arbitrary strings, which is very fragile to use for more advanced operations, such as checkpoints recovery. That's why Flink hashes the UIDs internally again, which is what you observe.

If you want to identify your operator in logs and web UI, you should use `name` in addition to `uid`.